# Make Outlook folder homepage launch popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I try to find out how to set a Outlook folder homepage that opens in Internet Explorer and not in Outlook.
I created a page with a redirection in the load event of the body, but the popup is blocked by the popup blocker, I try to add the website to the allowed one in the popup blocker settings, and it works if I browse the page in Internet Explorer, but it is still blocked in Outlook.

So I'm looking for a way to bypass this popup blocker without user interaction, and without disabling it.

Does someone know how to do this ?

How answers I found was like "it is not ok to spam the user", I agree, in a web context, but I disagree if it is needed by the end customer in a intranet context.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the popups are handled by Outlook which hosts the browser control, not the IE itself.

Have you tried to use the IE object model (InternetExplorer.Application) and launch a new instance of the browser?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry I took sometimes to write this comment.
I did not try this yet, I will, but I guess that if I use it in a web context, it will start the IE instance on the server and not the client workstation, isn't it ?

The context : a folder in Outlook has as home page the web page "home.aspx", hosted on a web server.

Comment: Either way you do it, it must be done in the client side script, not server, right?

Comment: Yes, from client side